# PCA, when applied on new data, performance collapsed

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I am using PCA to do dimension reduction, my training data has 1200000 records with 335 dimensions. Here is my code to train the model

```
X, y = load_data(f_file1)
valid_X, valid_y = load_data(f_file2)

pca = PCA(n_components=n_compo, whiten=True)
X = pca.fit_transform(X)
valid_input = pca.transform(valid_X)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy', max_depth=30, 
          min_samples_leaf=2, class_weight={0: 10, 1: 1})  # imbalanced class
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(clf.score(X_train, y_train)*100, 
      clf.score(X_test, y_test)*100,
      recall_score(y_train, clf.predict(X_train))*100, 
      recall_score(y_test, clf.predict(X_test))*100,
      precision_score(y_train, clf.predict(X_train))*100, 
      precision_score(y_test, clf.predict(X_test))*100,
      auc(*roc_curve(y_train, clf.predict_proba(X_train)[:, 1], pos_label=1)[:-1])*100,
      auc(*roc_curve(y_test, clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1], pos_label=1)[:-1])*100)

print(precision_score(valid_y, clf.predict(valid_input))*100, 
      recall_score(valid_y, clf.predict(valid_input))*100,
      accuracy_score(valid_y, clf.predict(valid_input))*100,
      auc(*roc_curve(valid_y, clf.predict_proba(valid_input)[:, 1], pos_label=1)[:-1])*100)
```

The output is

```
99.80, 99.32, 99.87, 99.88, 99.74, 98.78, 99.99, 99.46
0.00, 0.00, 97.13, 49.98, 700.69
```

So the recall and precision are 0s. Why PCA seems doesn't work on validate data and is the model got overfitted?

Comment: You should be fitting the pca on X_train only, and then do the transform() on X_test. Currently you are doing PCA over whole X and then splitting it into train and test, which will be overfitting.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's overfitted because

```
max_depth=30
```

It's too much.

How did you select PCA dimension? Optimal value you can get via eigenvectors/eigenvalues approach:

```
data = data.values
mean = np.mean(data.T, axis=1)
demeaned = data - mean
evals, evecs = np.linalg.eig(np.cov(demeaned.T))
order = evals.argsort()[::-1]

evals = evals[order]

plt.plot(evals)
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig('_!pca.png')
```

Optimal values you select by x values where line drop down to very zero.